# What is the meaning of tilde arrow in this context?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

This is the code from https://github.com/eigengo/activator-spray-twitter/blob/master/src/main/scala/core/tweetstream.scala

What ~>(tilde arrow) operator does? I think that must be a operator of HttpRequest, but I could not find such operator in spray API.

I can figure out that authorize is a function which returns (HttpRequest => HttpRequest), so val rq must be a HttpRequest which returned value after applied by returned function of authorize.

```
def receive: Receive = {
    case query: String =>
      val body = HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), s"track=$query")
      val rq = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, uri = uri, entity = body) ~> authorize
      sendTo(io).withResponsesReceivedBy(self)(rq)
    case ChunkedResponseStart(_) =>
    case MessageChunk(entity, _) => TweetUnmarshaller(entity).fold(_ => (), processor !)
    case _ =>
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator is just a function, and it is defined implicitly, see [line 32 here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.3/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/TransformerPipelineSupport.scala#L32).

Just think of it as *compose*. The operator takes the value to the left, and stuffs it as input into the function to the right.

A tip for how to find out things like these for yourself: Load the project into intellij idea or scala-IDE and just ctrl-click on the symbol. The IDE will take you to the definition.